# Finding best matching string from a list of strings

Tags: python, string-matching, difflib

Been trying to find the closest match to a string from a list of strings.

I've used "difflib" module : https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

but the results not always as expected.

Example:

```
import difflib

words_list = ['sprite','coke','lemon sparkling water']

difflib.get_close_matches('watter',words_list)
```

result:

```
[]
```

and I want the result to be:

```
['lemon sparkling water']
```

if the list would be:

```
words_list = ['sprite','coke','lemon sparkling water','water']
```

the query would have worked

How can I make it work without "water" being the first word in the string?

thanks

Comment: You might have to define what you mean by "closest match".  `difflib` probably doesn't consider that to be a "close match" because most of the string doesn't match.  For your particular example you could do `[w for w in words_list if 'water' in w]`, but that wouldn't work if the exact word "water" wasn't in the string.

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `[s for s in words_list if any(difflib.get_close_matches('water', word) for word in s.split())]`?

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to create bigrams? Or something similar with the cosine similarity? You need vector embeddings of your strings in these cases, though.

Comment: You could instead make your own function for closest match by the number of characters that match divided by total characters present.

Comment: Why does `words_list` contain sentences consisting of multiple words?

Comment: Just bad nameing. Call it products list and i'm searching for the most similar product

Answer (score 4):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), you can set the *cutoff* value to lower the standards for comparison:

```py
import difflib

words_list = ['sprite','coke','lemon sparkling water']
print(difflib.get_close_matches('watter',words_list,cutoff=.35))
```

Output:

```
['lemon sparkling water']
```

Comment: Extra arguments `, 1, 0` seem closer to "closest match" to me.

Comment: I think the cutoff is a bit problematic. it solves this exact problem but if I query 'watef' the result (with cutoff 0.35) will be ['sprite']

Comment: @KellyBundy Depends if you want `goobledegook` to return `coke`.

Comment: @tumir It's an algorithm.  The `difflib` algorithm scores `sprite` higher.  Use `n=len(words_list), cutoff=0` to get a ranked list of all the words according to the algorithm.

Comment: Well, if `coke` is closest, then it's closest :-)

Comment: I understand it's an algorithm and those are the results, been wondering if someone could suggest different methods like Levenshtein distance or fuzzy matching?

Comment: @tumir That wasn't your question and library recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Wasn't looking for library recommendations looking for algorithms and methods to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio as the `key` parameter for the `max` function. To facilitate this make a subclass of difflib.SequenceMatcher with a `__call__()` attribute.

```
import difflib

class SM(difflib.SequenceMatcher):
    def __init__(self,a):
        super().__init__(a=a)
    def __call__(self,b):
        self.set_seq2(b)
        return self.ratio()
```

Subclass instances are made with the *known* string. A second string, to be matched, must be passed when calling an instance. Because the instance is callable it can be used as `max`'s key argument.

```
words_list = ['sprite','coke','lemon sparkling water']

water = SM('water')
best = max(words_list, key=water)
```

---

Caveat - you have to accept the result of the difflib `measure of the sequences’ similarity`.